How can I download Stack Overflow data for AI training purposes?
I (hypothetically) represent a generative AI company and I want to access Stack Overflow data for AI training purposes. How can I do so legally?

Are you asking where to get the data or are you asking about the licensing of that data?

Contact Stack directly for business inquiries

Stack Exchange routinely provides quarterly data dumps. It comes with the same license as the original contribute, so your AI model, would also have to comply.

@SecurityHound It is illegal to use the data dumps for AI training purposes, due to the checkbox.

A checkbox is not a law.

@CriticizeSEactionsmeansban - So you have your answer, if your unable to comply with the license, then your unable to train your AI model on that data. By the way I don’t give you permission to use my contributions to train your AI model.

@SecurityHound that is not the answer complete since Stack Overflow is known to sell data dumps that can be used for AI training purposes. So what is the process for buying one of those?

@CriticizeSEactionsmeansban which is a business product. MSO is not for stack's business solutions.

Nevertheless I think this question is fine. The answer is just “go download the data dumps, nobody can stop you”; this isn’t a question that only the company can answer.

Please keep the comments focused on this question, and not, for example, the asker's name, any suspensions, unrelated policies, etc.  Also, reminder that answering in the comments is discouraged.

This question is similar to: Download Stack Overflow database. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

I'm voting as not a duplicate since that doesn't cover AI. I think the question is already clear that it's about AI while the linked question is clear that it's not about AI. I think it's already clear by the checkbox that Stack Exchange sees AI uses an non-AI uses as having different terms and conditions.

To do it in a way SE is happy with, you'd contact them and ask for pricing on overflow API.
Legally is complicated, and the compatibility of the CC licence and feeding it into a LLM is debatable, and outside the scope of this answer. You can find many conversations and posts on the topic across various meta sites.


How can I download Stack Overflow data for AI training purposes?

Here:
All Stack Exchange data dump releases
FYI: Is it illegal for a firm to train an AI model on a CC BY-SA 4.0 corpus and make a commercial use of it without distributing the model under CC BY-SA?

Why are people downvoting this? This is obviously the correct choice.
